# Wordpress site in a subdirectory does not redirect correctly to posts due to .htaccess in parent folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have this strange case... I have a wordpress site which is installed in a folder (example) inside another site. This is so, because the wordpress site belongs to a parked domain (example.net).

So! In the folder of my main site I have this .htaccess

```
## rules for error documents
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

## no trailing slash policy
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

## rewrite html pages if there is a present php equivalent
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

## if 'examle' is required, take us to the example.net domain
RewriteRule ^example - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess of the wordpress site is the default one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I can successfully open the home page of the Wordpress site, however, when I try to go to some of its pages/posts, I see the error

**The page isn’t redirecting properly**

*I am on Apache 2.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. It turned out (I did not know) no trailing slash policy breaks Wordpress. It strictly requires that trailing slashes are preserver.

The solution was to write the no-trailing-slash policy in such a way, so it will not be executed if you access the wordpress site.

In my case I changed the rule to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```